# Unit Testing Mock/Stub definitions in Moq

Tags: unit-testing, testing, moq

Any reading or advice I've been given on Unit Testing has always suggested a distinct difference between the definition of a Mock and a Stub. My current understanding of these definitions are as follows

> Mock: A fake which will be used in
>   your test to make a final assertion
>
> Stub: A fake which will be used in
>   your test to isolate a dependency but
>   not be asserted

However, Moq appears to only allow the creation of Mocks. The Stub namespace in the framework appears to be depreciated with recommendations to use Mock.SetupXXX.

Am I missing something in my understanding of this? Or is there a general understanding that a mock object can infact be used as nothing more that a stub?

Perhaps I am being pedantic, it's just that I have always found language in programming to be very strict and prefer to get my usage of it correct, especially when other developers might be taking over a project.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to the [Moq project site](https://github.com/Moq/moq4), Moq provides:

> Granular control over mock behavior with a simple [MockBehavior](http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/Moq/Moq/MockBehavior) enumeration (no need to learn what's the theoretical difference between a mock, a stub, a fake, a dynamic mock, etc.)

The lack of distinction between mocks, stubs, and such is a deliberate design decision; A design decision which I, for one, prefer. If I need a *true* mock, I call `Verify()` on it. If not, there's no `Verify()`. I like the simplicity, and I haven't found myself missing the distinction between `mock` and `stub`.

Answer (score 11):

Martin Fowler wrote a good article, [Mocks Aren't Stubs](http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html), which I think makes the distinction clear.

Mocks are used for behavior verification, while stubs supply fake data and normally participate in state verification.

Comment: but the behavior verification relates to the data involved, even if that data is hold in a different way. Sure the terms are clearly defined, but that doesn't mean it warrants not being flexible where that distinction is clearly blurred as well.

Comment: @eglasius Sure.  I have no problem with a library thinking it's handing me what it calls a mock even though I want to use it as a stub.  I'll just name the variable appropriately to my use.

Comment: +1 definitely agree, if the team feels its important to communicate the distinction, naming of the variable will clear that up.

Answer (score 3):

imho its just that its kind of a silly discussion.

What matters is that you use the mocks/stubs to assert what you need to in the test, and don't assert what you don't.

Comment: I disagree eglasius. Tests are supposed to be extremely easy to read, digest and understand what is being performed by other developers. Language plays a pivotal role in this.

Comment: @WDuffy sure, but the way I see is that's already communicated clearly in the code of the test to achieve these.

Comment: Differentiating Stubs from Mocks is useful to indicate to the reader of the test to know which messages are relevant to the current test (expectations) from the incidental ones (stubs)

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, Moq can create true stubs.  From the [Moq Quick Start page](http://code.google.com/p/moq/wiki/QuickStart):

```
* Setup a property so that it will automatically start tracking its value (also known as Stub):

  // start "tracking" sets/gets to this property
  mock.SetupProperty(f => f.Name);

  // alternatively, provide a default value for the stubbed property
  mock.SetupProperty(f => f.Name, "foo");


  // Now you can do:

  IFoo foo = mock.Object;
  // Initial value was stored
  Assert.Equal("foo", foo.Name);

  // New value set which changes the initial value
  foo.Name = "bar";
  Assert.Equal("bar", foo.Name);

* Stub all properties on a mock (not available on Silverlight):

  mock.SetupAllProperties();
```

IMHO, the distinctions between flavors of fakes is best thought of as a distinction between *functions* of those fakes rather than *types* of fakes, as a fake may take on multiple roles at once (e.g. can be a true mock and a saboteur all at once), and as no such distinction is necessary for using a mock framework.  (I should blog about this!)